# How to get the previous 6 weeks result for this week in mysql

Tags: mysql

I can get the total entries for each week with the code below.

```
select week(date_created) as week, count(distinct tag_code) as Total_This_Week 
from entries 
where date_created between '2000-01-01' and '2020-01-01' 
group by week;
```

But what I need to get is the `total_last_6_weeks` column like below which is the previous 6 weeks added up so for week 6 the `total_Last_6_weeks` is '370' is gotten by adding up (56+45+85+34+85+65). And this must happen every week so for week 9 it must add up the previous 6 weeks. Everything I've tried does not seem to work.

```
+-----+-----------------+--------------------+ 
| week| Total_This_Week | total_Last_6_Weeks | 
+-----+-----------------+--------------------+ 
|__0__|_______81________|_______ 122________ | 
|__1__|_______65________|________188________ | 
|__2__|_______85________|________145_________| 
|__3__|_______34________|________205_________| 
|__4__|_______85________|________189_________| 
|__5__|_______45________|________112_________| 
|__6__|_______56________|________370_________| 
|__7__|_______32________|________518_________| 
|__8__|_______34________|________121_________| 
|__9__|_______45________|________224_________| 
+-----+-----------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server or Oracle you could lag the `date_created` by six weeks and use

```
    over (partition by ...)
```

to get the cumulative sums, while the difference would give you the sum for 6 weeks on a rolling basis.
I understand that in MySQL you can do this via using variables, as partition and over do not directly exist. Here is a brief summary of how to go about it:

[ROW_NUMBER, Partition and Over in MySQL](http://briansteffens.com/2011/07/19/row_number-partition-and-over-in-mysql/)